# ld: framework not found KudanAR

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, kudan

I have getting iOS SDK(1.3.1) for KudanAR.

I tried to builded the KudanARsample in Xcode.

However, you will see an error such as the following.

> ld: framework not found KudanAR
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am installed already 'KudanAR.framework'.

I wonder if the packages is missing?

Download from:
https://github.com/kudan-eu/Simple-Samples-iOS

Development environment:
Xcode 8.0,iOS 10,OS X

Please answer....

Answer (score 0):

As the README instructions say:

> In order for this sample project to work, you will need to download the KudanAR framework from the Kudan website. Then simply drop the framework into the root project directory and run the Xcode project.

You can get it from [the Kudan website](http://www.kudan.eu/download)

Comment: >Then simply drop the framework into the root project directory and run the Xcode project.
You can get it from the Kudan website